# Website not looking nice on higer zoom level

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have built and website with standard 100% zoom . Now in many laptops by default it has 150% recommended zoom, it causes my website to not have great look and feel.

How can i force my applciation to start with 100% zoom always .

I have tried zoom css (Not recommended though), but it doesn't work in safari and Firefox.
ALso tried changing initial-scale in meta tag i.e

. Bjut no luck. Kindly help , Thanks.

Comment: Generally trying to force a specific condition on the visitor of a website is a battle you cannot win. And should not even try. Always assume that your visitors will use your website from various different devices and strive to be unassuming as possible. Yes, this will result in more work, to accommodate a multitude of screen resolutions, orientations, touch vs mouse, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent the user from using the zoom feature in their browser, but you can *suggest* an initial scale when the page first loads. Add this header to your html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It's up to the browser what they do with this information. Some users with sight impairment may have the browser set to ignore this feature as an accessibility option. There's no way to bypass this.

Instead, consider how you might be able to adjust your website to work well in these conditions. You can use higher DPI images, responsive templating, things like that.